# how to make vmware API for tags and ip address link?

Tags: api, tags, vmware

is there any api for the vmware virtual machine tags and ip addresses fetching and joining them... for example vm1 would have an ip of 1.1.1.1 and user defined tags like app=db...

I can query the tags but doesn't map to virtual machine nor iP address...
i used cis tags api but none provide the useful output....

```
        vsession = self.vCenterSession()
        #print(vsession)
        all_tags = 
        vsession.get('https://10.156.0.10/rest/com/vmware/cis/tagging/tag')
        all_tags_py = json.loads(all_tags.text)['value']
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to combine several calls together to pull all that information.

- Retrieve the VM ID with: [List VM](https://developer.vmware.com/docs/vsphere-automation/latest/vcenter/api/vcenter/vm/get/)
- Retrieve the VM's IP by referencing the VM ID with: [List Guest Network Interfaces](https://developer.vmware.com/docs/vsphere-automation/latest/vcenter/api/vcenter/vm/vm/guest/networking/interfaces/get/)
- Retrieve the Tag ID with: [List Tag](https://developer.vmware.com/docs/vsphere-automation/latest/cis/api/cis/tagging/tag/get/)
- Update the tag with: [Update Tag](https://developer.vmware.com/docs/vsphere-automation/latest/cis/api/cis/tagging/tag/tag_id/patch/)

Comment: question is how you could glue them together ? did you try? my tests output have no pointers to glue them.

Comment: Yes, I've done the above a lot. Which of your tests doesn't have output? Generally if there's no output, then it didn't find a resource (VM, IP, Tag) for you to use.